# Не получается установить kivy. python

Tags: python, kivy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед тем как ввести python -m pip install kivy, ввёл вот это:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2 kivy_deps.glew

Всё обновилось и установилось кроме киви.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Явно проблема с зависимостями. Можно попробовать создать отдельное conda окружение и в нем с нуля все установить.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: Xyanight, именно отсюда всё вписывал

Comment: Какая версия python?

Comment: Александр, python 3.8

Comment: Kivy не поддерживает пока работу с Python 3.8!

Comment: @Xyanight а можно ли установить пайтоне 3.7 в папку с пайтоне 3.8 или лучше 3.8 удалить и установить 3.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С 3.8 официальная 1.11.1 версия Kivy не работает.

Но, как [пишут](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563#issuecomment-560039155), можно установить из мастер ветки, где всё должно работать:

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Answer (score 0):

Я для установки Kivy использовал виртуальную машину с Linux cистемой.

1. Устанавливаем все зависимости с помощью [шелл скрипта](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD-data/blob/master/install-kivy-buildozer-dependencies.sh).

   Как написал Zvorian : В последнее время java 8 не устанавливается обычным способом. Устанавливайте здесь - https://pkgs.org/download/oracle-java8-installer у меня сработало...

   Потом : делаем действие под номером 2 ([Решение взято отсюда](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/894))

   OS: Ubuntu 18.04  (Я делал это на Минте)

   Installing Java version 8 fixed this issue for me.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
   ```

   I used the following cmd line to interactively change default java version.
2. `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

   Нас попросят выбрать версию джавы. Вы выбираем ту что с восьмёркой.

   И после всего этого, опять вбиваем заветную buildozer android debug

   После этих действий начнётся некое скачивание всяких : Downloading sdl2_mixer и т.д и т.п