# Не получается установить framework kivy с Python 3.8

Tags: python, framework, kivy

В последний момент выводиться ошибка (выводится очень большой текст с красным цветом).

Возможно это ошибка из-за версии питона, она у меня последней версии `3.8.0`.

[image: начало ошибки]

Comment: Похожий вопрос вроде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1059658/15479

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Можно закрыть этот вопрос как дупликат [вот того](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177436/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-kivy-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-3-8-ubuntu), хотя этот раньше? Просто тот лучше...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С 3.8 официальная 1.11.1 версия Kivy не работает.

Но, как [пишут](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563#issuecomment-560039155), можно установить из мастер ветки, где всё должно работать:

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Answer (score 0):

Не работает Python 3.8 c Kivy пока!