# Не могу установить kivy на python 3.8 ubuntu

Tags: python, kivy, install

Не могу установить kivy на python 3.8 ubuntu

```
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b0rnt7_h/kivy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b0rnt7_h/kivy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-b0rnt7_h/kivy/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-b0rnt7_h/kivy/
    Complete output (80 lines):
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-aqiudvwe/cython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-aqiudvwe/cython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-cgiqrqcw
           cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-aqiudvwe/cython/
      Complete output (7 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
    
      error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
     WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpwhzzkdu8', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-install-b0rnt7_h/kivy/setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 718, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 777, in fetch_build_egg
         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
       File "/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/home/hulimulushka/coding/python/kivy_venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpwhzzkdu8', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Using setuptools
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
    
    b"Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer-1.0.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'gstreamer-1.0' found\n"
    
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)
    
    b"Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'sdl2' found\nPackage SDL2_ttf was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_ttf.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'SDL2_ttf' found\nPackage SDL2_image was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_image.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'SDL2_image' found\nPackage SDL2_mixer was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_mixer.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'SDL2_mixer' found\n"
    
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags pangoft2 (code 1)
    
    b"Package pangoft2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `pangoft2.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'pangoft2' found\n"
    
    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.8:

```
pip3 install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```